# Nativescript tns deployment commands

Tags: android, ios, mobile, nativescript

I got questions about deployment tns commands.
Even after reading the docs and `tns --help`, things are still unclear to me. So, here we go:

- Why `--watch` is necessary for `livesync`, isn't it the purpose of live syncing?
- Is there a reason or situation I should prefer `livesync` over `run --watch` or `debug --watch`?
- When `--emulator` is necessary? Only to call ios simulator and android official emulator? I've been using genymotion so I assume it pretends it's a real device. Is it always correct? Any other "fake" real device I should consider?
- Where/how can I check what exactly is going on in the device/emulator? I mean, I'm under the impression that `livesync` only deploys changes, subsequent `run`s don't do the same?
- What kind of changes requires a full deployment on device/emulator? I mean, complete uninstall before hitting `livesync`, `run` or `debug`
- What kind of changes requires a full platform rebuild? Removing and `tns platform add`ing back?
  Sorry for so many questions, but imho this topic is worth a more detailed article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `--watch` enables re-occurring liveSync's.   Without the `--watch` it just sync it up once and is done.  In all reality not using `--watch` is probably fairly pointless; but there might be some case where you only want it liveSync'd once.
2. `run --watch` = `livesync --watch`   `run` (w/o --watch) !=  `livesync`
3. `--emulator` will allow TNS to actually start an emulator, however if an Android emulator is already started then it is not needed as a android Emulator shows up as a "real" android device.    `--emulator` for iOS is needed to force it to use the simulator.
4. No way that I know of to really know what is going in, `--watch` or `livesync` only reports it synced files; it doesn't give you a list.
5. The reason to use a `run` would be if you change ANYTHING in the `app_resources/` folder AND/OR add/modify a plugin (anything in the node_modules).   Both of those require a complete rebuild.  Please note doing a `tns run --watch` will NOT do a rebuild; it will just sync.  You need to do a `tns run` then after it rebuilds and installs the new version, you can do a `--watch`
6. You shouldn't have to normally remove/re-add the platforms, but there are some weird corner cases where a `tns run` or you deleting the app off the device and then doing a `tns run` doesn't seem to pick up your changes.   This is more a last ditch fix.    On iOS if you update a plugin and it updates a POD, this is one of the cases you should reset your platforms folder.

One thing I need to stress; `tns run --watch` === `tns livesync --watch`; this means even though you THINK you are doing a `tns run` you AREN'T if you add the `--watch` to it.   I do have a bug report in for this; but as of v2.4 it is still annoyingly/deceptively broken...